# Lost Macros in Microsoft Word Global Template

Tags: vba, ms-word

All the macros I stored in the Normal.dotm global template of my Word 2007 document are gone except one minor one. This is the second time this has happened to me. (I know, I should've learned from the first time.)

Is there any way to recover them? Is there any way to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: I think you did something which caused that situation. You need to think of all Office/Word changes, reinstallations, upgrades, file movements, other situation to find out what have happened. I store lots macros in that file for months and nothing similar happened...

Comment: Thanks for your input, KazJaw.

No reinstallations.
No upgrades. 
File movements? But that's not supposed to affect the Normal template.

A related question. I have a BAK file in the Template folder. It seems it's a kind of back up folder. Do you know how I can access it/use it to recover my lost information?

Comment: `BAK` files used to be `backup files`. Try to change it's name into 'Normal_bak.dotm' and try to run it. Do not change it's name into `Normal.dotm` which could be risky.

Comment: Thanks so much for your engagement in this. 

Turns out the solution is easy. Just follow the instructions! 

In this case, it was a BAK for MS Word, so I opened MS Word, navigated to the BAK file, and opened it with MS Word. The missing files appeared in my VBA file.

Comment: For what it's worth, I finally noticed this specifically happens to me when I open multiple fles from Explorer...  highlight multiple and hit Enter...  my Normal.dotm gets replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. For security purposes, our IT department has a program that each evening wipes out almost all of the macros saved to Normal.dotm on each individual's computer.

You will need to setup a Word Template that is Macro Enabled. Any macros you create need to be built directly in this template. You can do this by going into Word and selecting "File" and then "Open" instead of clicking on the template file on your server or desktop.

Answer (score 5):

Go to \Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
and see if there is a Normal.dotm.old or .bak files. Rename them and see if your lost data is there.

It worked for me too!

Comment: This keeps happening to me every couple months... no idea why.  My Normal.dotm gets replaced.  I can see a new datetime on it.  I keep a backup of Normal.dotm in this folder and just replace it.  -- edited this answer to point out this option explicitly :)

Comment: I can confirm, this works. It saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Solved for me. I found backup of normal.dotm in .wbk format

Answer (score 0):

Once your macros are back, while Word is active:

1. Press Alt+F11 to open your Macro manager.
2. In the left-hand pane, see the items under Modules.
3. This or these item(s) contain(s) macro(s).
4. Right click on each item and choose "Export file..."
5. Save the file to a safe place that you an remember.
   (You can write a macro to do all of this!)

When you lose your macros again, restore them:

1. Press Alt+F11 to open your Macro manager.
2. In the left-hand pane, right-click on "Modules".
3. Chose "Import file..."
4. Navigate to your saved macros file and open it.